Is the "Interactive" CPU governor available for ubuntu 24.04.1?
This was asked before, regarding an earlier version, with the last update to that question almost 7 years ago.
I would like to use the interactive governor with ubuntu 24.04.1 x64 desktop.
Can I?
Will I notice a difference in perceived interactive performance?
What is required to acquire, compile, install, activate, and automatically activate it at boot time?

I don't see it mentioned in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt, so I doubt it has been merged into mainline, so the answers there still apply.

This question is similar to: interactive cpu governor?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
